# How do I rename a resources routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

How do I rename some of these routes...for example, below i want to use signup_path in my controllers instead of signup_sessions_path...

```
 resources :sessions, only: [] do
        collection do
          post    :signup, :as => :signup
          post    :login
          delete  :logout
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to nest the routes under resources :sessions but rather use the to: option like so:

```
post :signup, to: 'sessions#signup', as: :signup, on: :collection
```

Not too sure about your collection there but I'm sure you get the gist of it

### Update

According to your comment, as of today, I don't know of any way to remove the nested route resource name from the path name of a nested resource route. In other words, whatever is nested is purposely to use the scope of the resource and therefore there are no options to revert that behaviour other than taking it out of the resource's block.

Comment: I am aware of this but i want to use 'resources' instead of the format u recommend. I looked at the code and it doesnt seem like 'resources' is capable of this.

Comment: Well no. Whatever is nested is purposely to use the scope of the resource. It don't get why on Earth you'd want to change that? Why would you want to nest the path under the resource only to have an option saying it shouldn't be nested??

Comment: LOL!!!! consistency of my other code....that's about all! Was just wondering it its possible, thanks.

Comment: lol no problem :) I've updated the answer to reflect your 'real' question